# Alterar cor de DIV quando clicarmos com condição (JS)

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

Estou iniciando no js e estava realizando alguns estudos e praticando, porém me travei aqui, gostaria de trocar a cor dessas três DIVs quando clicarmos individualmente em cada uma para amarelo, mas quando clicássemos de volta na mesma, retornasse a cor padrão que era preto.
Tentei aplicar alguns IFs mas sem sucesso em como condicionar utilizando a cor padrão, alguém conseguiria dar uma luz por favor?

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

        <div id="jan1"></div>
        <div id="jan2"></div>
        <div id="jan3"></div>
        <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0; 
    background: green;
    /*display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;*/
}

#jan1{
    width: 80px;
    height: 120px;
    background: black;
    display: inline-block;
}

#jan2{
    width: 80px;
    height: 120px;
    background: black;
    display: inline-block;
}

#jan3{
    width: 80px;
    height: 120px;
    background: black;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

**JS**

```
let jan1 = document.getElementById('jan1');
let jan2 = document.getElementById('jan2');
let jan3 = document.getElementById('jan3');

jan1.addEventListener('click', () =>{
        jan1.style.background = 'yellow';
})

jan2.addEventListener('click', () =>{
        jan2.style.background = 'yellow';
})

jan3.addEventListener('click', () =>{
        jan3.style.background = 'yellow';
})
```

Comment: Cara crie uma classe tipo .yellow {background: yellow}, e quando vc clicar no elemento vc faz um toggleClass

Comment: @hugocsl bacana, nem cheguei a pensar dessa forma, agradeço

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seria mais fácil por esse estilo numa classe, e usar o `toggle` para adicionar/remover a classe:

```js
// use a classe "trocacor" para pegar todos os divs de uma vez e reaproveitar o código
document.querySelectorAll('.trocacor').forEach(div => {
  // para cada div, adiciono o evento click
  div.addEventListener('click', event => {
    // faz o toggle da classe, adiciona se não exitir, remove se existir
    div.classList.toggle('amarelo');
  })
})
```

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0; 
    background: green;
    /*display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;*/
}

#jan1{
    width: 80px;
    height: 120px;
    background: black;
    display: inline-block;
}

#jan2{
    width: 80px;
    height: 120px;
    background: black;
    display: inline-block;
}

#jan3{
    width: 80px;
    height: 120px;
    background: black;
    display: inline-block;
}

.amarelo {
  background-color: yellow !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="trocacor" id="jan1"></div>
<div class="trocacor" id="jan2"></div>
<div class="trocacor" id="jan3"></div>
```

Comment: Opa amigo, exatamente isso que precisava, nem me passou pela mente dessa forma, lhe agradeço

Comment: Se resolveu seu problema, vota na pergunta.